# Deleting 3 days old file from folder in php

Tags: php, glob, unlink, scandir

I have a folder that has files with names

```
2014-01-28_backup.txt
2014-01-25_backup.txt
2014-01-26_backup.txt
2014-01-27_backup.txt
```

I want to create a script that deletes 3 days old file, so If I run the script on 2014-01-29, It should delete all the files prior to 26.
I have seen a function called glob and scandir but not sure how to get that in

Comment: The one who votes to close please write comment as wellThnks

Comment: @SamiraKhorshidi I haven't accepted any, that was a purely mistake..

Comment: could you not use logrotate for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$threeDbefore = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-3 days"));
foreach(glob("path/to/files/*") as $file) {
    if (!is_file($file)) {
        continue;
    }
    $fileParts = explode('_', basename($file));
    if(!empty($fileParts[0]) && $fileParts[0] <= $threeDbefore) {
        unlink($file);
    }
}
```

This will also delete files before 3 days, not just exactly 3 days. i.e it will delete `'2014-01-24_backup.txt` and `2014-01-23_backup.txt` etc

Answer (score 1):

Of course your folder and files must have write permission ( `chmod 777` )

```
foreach (glob("path/to/files/*") as $file) {
    if(substr(basename($file), 0, 10) <= date("Y-m-d",strtotime("-3 days"))) 
    unlink($file);
}
```

Comment: Fllah shouldn't it look for _backup.txt as well?

Comment: are not all your files named ...`_backup.txt` ?

Comment: yes all files has this pattern in the end

Comment: so no problem, this is working, `glob` finds file with given pattern,  `WORD*` means all files starting with `WORD`

Comment: did it solved your problem dude ?

Comment: but i am not getting where are you giving pattern?

Comment: in `$dir.date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-3 days"))."*"` its like : `path/to/files/2014-01-26*`

Comment: I think  user wants this

Comment: @AlirezaFallah it should delete all files older than 3 days

Comment: @dhavald that helps, the explode plays vital role :)

Comment: @user1765876 : I updated my answer. look at it